# OxyPlot in ListView WPF deos not display anything

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

If I use:

```
<oxy:PlotView  MinHeight="260" Height="Auto"   IsRendering="True" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="8" Model="{Binding PlotM}">
                        </oxy:PlotView>
```

It displays the plot correctly.

If I use this code:

```
<ListView Name="PlotLista"  ItemsSource="{Binding PlotModelList}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <oxy:PlotView  MinHeight="260" Height="Auto"   IsRendering="True" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="8" Model="{Binding}">
              </oxy:PlotView>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

It display a list of bkank elements and no OxyPlot is showed. PlotModelList is `List<PlotModel>`

Comment: Model="{Binding},  should it be Model="{Binding PlotM}" ?

Comment: No, PlotM is PlotModel and PlotModelList is List<PlotModel>.

Comment: You're setting MinHeight of the PlotView element. Does it probably also need a Width or MinWidth, or at least something like `HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch` in the ListViewItem Style?

Comment: Or try to bind to `ObservableCollection<PlotModel>`, instead of `List<PlotModel>`. If the `List<PlotModel>` is populated _after_ the binding,  your `ListView` will not be notified of the changes in the List and it will remain empty.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was Width and Height:

```
     <ListView Name="PlotLista"  ItemsSource="{Binding PlotModelList}" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <oxy:PlotView  MinHeight="260" Height="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="700"   IsRendering="True" 
FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="8" Model="{Binding}">
                                </oxy:PlotView>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```